# How to combine XML siblings within XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to combine 2 sibling nodes values using XSLT. I already have an XSLT sheet that already combines identical nodes, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to combine the 2 sibling nodes without messing up whats already in place.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
    <ROW xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
      <Sign_Type>BB-1</Sign_Type>
      <fm:Floor xmlns="">1</fm:Floor>
      <fm:Location xmlns="">2</fm:Location>
      <Line1>ELEVATOR MACHINE ROOM 107</Line1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
      <Sign_Type>BB-1</Sign_Type>
      <fm:Floor xmlns="">1</fm:Floor>
      <fm:Location xmlns="">3</fm:Location>
      <Line1>ELEVATOR MACHINE ROOM 107</Line1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
      <Sign_Type>BB-1</Sign_Type>
      <fm:Floor xmlns="">1</fm:Floor>
      <fm:Location xmlns="">4</fm:Location>
      <Line1>ELEVATOR MACHINE ROOM 107</Line1>
    </ROW>
    <ROW xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
      <Sign_Type>BB-1</Sign_Type>
      <fm:Floor xmlns="">1</fm:Floor>
      <fm:Location xmlns="">5</fm:Location>
      <Line1>ELEVATOR MACHINE ROOM 107</Line1>
    </ROW>
  </root>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="artTypeNames" match="fm:ROW" use="concat(fm:Sign_Type, '||', fm:Line1)"/>
 <xsl:template match="fm:FMPDSORESULT">
    <ROOT>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:ROW[count(. | key('artTypeNames', concat(fm:Sign_Type, '||', fm:Line1))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="fm:Sign_Type" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ROOT>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="fm:ROW">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:Sign_Type" />

            <fm:Location>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('artTypeNames', concat(fm:Sign_Type,   '||', fm:Line1))/fm:Location" /> 
            </fm:Location>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:Line1" />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fm:Location">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What the output should look like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
    <ROW xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
      <Sign_Type>BB-1</Sign_Type>
      <fm:Location xmlns="">1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 1-5</fm:Location>
      <Line1>ELEVATOR MACHINE ROOM 107</Line1>
    </ROW>
  </root>
```

Anybody can help me pinpoint where and what I need to change to make this work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is just a typo in your code, but your first template matches on the element **FMPDSORESULT** which does not exist in your XML sample!

```
<xsl:template match="fm:FMPDSORESULT">
```

As this does not match anything, the built-in templates apply, and they will end up using the template that matches **fm:ROW** for each of the four **ROW** elements in your XML.

You should be matching on the **root** element

```
<xsl:template match="root">
```

As for combining-siblings, I think you are saying you wish to output the **Floor** element along with the **Location** element. You can just use preceding-sibling here for example.

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::fm:Floor[1]" />
```

Alternatively, this syntax will also work; just get the only **Floor** element for the current parent

```
<xsl:value-of select="../fm:Floor" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="artTypeNames" match="fm:ROW" use="concat(fm:Sign_Type, '||', fm:Line1)"/>
 <xsl:template match="root">
    <ROOT>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:ROW[count(. | key('artTypeNames', concat(fm:Sign_Type, '||', fm:Line1))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="fm:Sign_Type" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ROOT>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="fm:ROW">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:Sign_Type" />

            <fm:Location>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('artTypeNames', concat(fm:Sign_Type,   '||', fm:Line1))/fm:Location" /> 
            </fm:Location>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fm:Line1" />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fm:Location">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="../fm:Floor" />
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yea it was a typo. I just pulled out a couple ROW elements as an example. Forgot the root element. It works pretty good too, thank you!